# IP Whitelist for EKS behind WAF

Tags: networking, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb

I'm looking for some guidance on implementing IP whitelisting. EKS cluster receives traffic through WAF (web application firewall) and I'd like to whitelist WAF IPs. I want to block all traffic other than that from the WAF.

The setup I have is:
Client >> WAF >> AWS LB (network LB) >> EKS >> ingress controller (nginx) >> pods

Right now the the WAF can be bypassed by directly sending requests to network LB.
Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since you are using network ELB, your nodes should already have a security group rule that allows access from client's IP to your cluster (probably 0.0.0.0/0). you need to change that rule and limit it to your WAF IPs